# type 'DateTime' is not a subtype of type 'String' in Flutter Cloud Firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, dart-pub

I'm trying to get DateTime.now() and write/read it with Cloud FireStore. But got the error

This is my code

**In the UI**

```dart
Text( 
DateFormat('dd/MM/yyyy kk:mm')
.format(DateTime
.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(int.parse(document[index].data['timeCreated']))),
style: timeStyle,
),
```

**Writing data to Firestore**

```dart
Firestore.instance.runTransaction((transaction) async {
      await transaction.set(
        docRef,
        {'timeCreated': DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString()},
      );
    });
```

And got this error

```
I/flutter ( 3378): Another exception was thrown: type 'DateTime' is not a subtype of type 'String'
```

Comment: did you try adding toString method at the end in text widget?

Comment: @VirenVVarasadiya Did you mean 
`DateFormat('dd/MM/yyyy kk:mm')
.format(DateTime
.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(int.parse(document[index].data['timeCreated']))).toString()`
I did but still the same error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert to string:

```
int time = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;
String t = "$time";
```

Answer (score 1):

Here, it is expecting type as 'String', but we are passing it as a 'DateTime' which is incorrect.

Formatting dates in the default 'en_US' format does not require any initialization.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/intl/DateFormat-class.html

So, we simply need to format it like:

```
var dateTime = DateTime.now()
DateFormat.E().format(dateTime)
```

E() is the constructor of DateFormat in Flutter which refers to first 3 letter of the week

You can refer the official doc for available constructors:

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/intl/DateFormat-class.html#constructors

**Note**:
Below is the version used for DateTime library ~ intl
intl: ^0.18.0

(https://pub.dev/packages/intl)